# Single observation in fixed-limit bar chart results in non-normal-width bar?

Tags: r, ggplot2, limit

I am trying to plot a bar chart with date as x-axis. I want to set the limits myself, but if I do so and have only a single observation in it, the bar gets really tiny.

```
# correct plot
economics2 <- economics %>%
  subset(date> "2010-01-01" & date < "2011-06-01") %>%
  head(2)

ggplot(economics2, aes(date, unemploy))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  scale_x_date(limits = as.Date(c("2009-01-01","2012-01-01")))
```

This produces a correct plot - but if I change head to 1, it produces a faulty plot:

```
# plot with error / slim bar
economics2 <- economics %>%
  subset(date> "2010-01-01" & date < "2011-06-01") %>%
  head(1)
  
ggplot(economics2, aes(date, unemploy))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  scale_x_date(limits = as.Date(c("2009-01-01","2012-01-01")))
```

I've already tried using xlim but it results in the same problem. If I fix the geom_bar argument width manually, it works. On the other hand I would have to come up with a solution on how to choose the correct bar width myself.

What am I missing?

Comment: if you look at your first plot it will not make sense because it is not placed correctly on the x date axis

Comment: How are you going to make a barplot on a continuous x axis? You need to think about this

Comment: @StupidWolf What do you mean it's not placed correctly? It seems fine to me. Do you have an idea about the bar width?